# How to check REST API does not contains Image Field in Response?

Tags: android, retrofit, field, response

I am using WordPress Rest API in that When a user does not upload image from WordPress backend it doest not contain that field and retrofit going in exception error like  org.json.JSONException: No value for thumbnail when user upload image than I am getting response on how to handle this when response does not have thumbnail field

```
    ApiInterface apiInterface = RetrofitManager.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<JsonObject> call = apiInterface.getPost(intValue);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                response.body();

                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                    Log.d("@@response", response.body().toString());
                    JSONObject jsonResult = jsonObject.getJSONObject("post");
                    String title = jsonResult.getString("title");
                    String expert = jsonResult.getString("excerpt");



                    if ( jsonResult.getString("thumbnail")== null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Image Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.sikarlogo).into(imageView);
                    } else {
                        imageUrl  = jsonResult.getString("thumbnail");
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);

                    }
                    tvContent.setText(expert);
                    tvTitle.setText(title);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Log.e("@Success", response.message());

            } else {
                Log.e("@NO Success", response.message());

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.d("@counselingError", "");
        }
    });
```

and response like that I am getting :

```
{
"status": "ok",
"post": {
    "id": 16,
    "type": "post",
    "slug": "%e0%a4%95%e0%a4%bf%e0%a4%a1%e0%a4%bc%e0%a4%9c%e0%a4%bc%e0%a5%80-%e0%a4%b8%e0%a5%80%e0%a4%95%e0%a4%b0-%e0%a4%ae%e0%a5%87%e0%a4%82-%e0%a4%ae%e0%a4%a8%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%af%e0%a4%be-%e0%a4%ac%e0%a4%be",
    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/index.php/2019/11/19/%e0%a4%95%e0%a4%bf%e0%a4%a1%e0%a4%bc%e0%a4%9c%e0%a4%bc%e0%a5%80-%e0%a4%b8%e0%a5%80%e0%a4%95%e0%a4%b0-%e0%a4%ae%e0%a5%87%e0%a4%82-%e0%a4%ae%e0%a4%a8%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%af%e0%a4%be-%e0%a4%ac%e0%a4%be/",
    "status": "publish",
    "title": "किड़ज़ी सीकर में मनाया बालदिवस।",
    "title_plain": "किड़ज़ी सीकर में मनाया बालदिवस।",
    "content": "",
    "excerpt": "सीकर के किड़ज़ी स्कूल में बाल दिवस को हर्षोल्लास के साथ मनाया गया। इस अवसर पर बच्चों ने विभिन्न मनोरंजक और खेल-कूद की गतिविधियों में भाग लिया जैसे म्यूज़िकल चेयर, बलून रेस, जलेबी रेस, फ़्री डाँस आदि। बच्चों को स्कूल की और से उपहार भी भेंट किए गए तथा उन्हें पंडित जवाहरलाल नेहरू के जीवन &hellip;",
    "date": "2019-11-19 10:32:55",
    "modified": "2019-11-19 10:34:46",
    "categories": [],
    "tags": [],
    "author": {
        "id": 2,
        "slug": "adminsikarsandesh-com",
        "name": "admin@sikarsandesh.com",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "nickname": "admin@sikarsandesh.com",
        "url": "",
        "description": ""
    },
    "comments": [],
    "attachments": [
        {
            "id": 17,
            "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg.jpg",
            "slug": "sikarimg",
            "title": "sikarimg",
            "description": "",
            "caption": "",
            "parent": 16,
            "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
            "images": {
                "full": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg.jpg",
                    "width": 960,
                    "height": 640
                },
                "thumbnail": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-150x150.jpg",
                    "width": 150,
                    "height": 150
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-300x200.jpg",
                    "width": 300,
                    "height": 200
                },
                "medium_large": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-768x512.jpg",
                    "width": 768,
                    "height": 512
                },
                "woohoo-small": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-104x74.jpg",
                    "width": 104,
                    "height": 74
                },
                "woohoo-large": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-850x491.jpg",
                    "width": 850,
                    "height": 491
                },
                "woohoo-full": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-960x540.jpg",
                    "width": 960,
                    "height": 540
                },
                "woohoo-widget": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-320x220.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 220
                },
                "bdaia-carousel": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-309x330.jpg",
                    "width": 309,
                    "height": 330
                },
                "bdaia-gallery-grid": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-850x567.jpg",
                    "width": 850,
                    "height": 567
                },
                "bdaia-gr1": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-742x490.jpg",
                    "width": 742,
                    "height": 490
                },
                "bdaia-gr2": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-496x244.jpg",
                    "width": 496,
                    "height": 244
                },
                "bdaia-gr3": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-618x260.jpg",
                    "width": 618,
                    "height": 260
                },
                "bdaia-gr4": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-413x244.jpg",
                    "width": 413,
                    "height": 244
                },
                "bdaia-small": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-104x74.jpg",
                    "width": 104,
                    "height": 74
                },
                "bdaia-large": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-850x491.jpg",
                    "width": 850,
                    "height": 491
                },
                "bdaia-full": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-960x540.jpg",
                    "width": 960,
                    "height": 540
                },
                "bdaia-widget": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-320x220.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 220
                },
                "bdaia-block11": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-384x220.jpg",
                    "width": 384,
                    "height": 220
                },
                "woocommerce_thumbnail": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-300x300.jpg",
                    "width": 300,
                    "height": 300
                },
                "woocommerce_single": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-600x400.jpg",
                    "width": 600,
                    "height": 400
                },
                "woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-100x100.jpg",
                    "width": 100,
                    "height": 100
                },
                "shop_catalog": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-300x300.jpg",
                    "width": 300,
                    "height": 300
                },
                "shop_single": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-600x400.jpg",
                    "width": 600,
                    "height": 400
                },
                "shop_thumbnail": {
                    "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-100x100.jpg",
                    "width": 100,
                    "height": 100
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "comment_count": 0,
    "comment_status": "open",
    "thumbnail": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-150x150.jpg",

        "shop_thumbnail": {
            "url": "https://sikarsandesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sikarimg-100x100.jpg",
            "width": 100,
            "height": 100
        }
    }
},
```

}

In some cases, I am not getting thumbnail field how to handle this Image field

finally I have done like that :

```
                    if ( jsonResult.has("thumbnail")) {
                        imageUrl  = jsonResult.getString("thumbnail");
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Image Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.sikarlogo).into(imageView);
                    }
```

Comment: How to handle when I am not getting Thumbnail field in response

Comment: You have already done that `if(jsonResult.getString("thumbnail")== null)`

Comment: it's not working

Comment: One condition is working and getting error exception: No value for thumbnail

Comment: Could we have a modification done at API level. They could pass emptyString  in thumbnail field if image is not uploaded.Could you let us know response in case image is not uploaded Are you facing while receiving response?

Comment: .has method working thank you all of you

Comment: @bugfreerammohan Please check my edit

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```
public String checkIfNull(JsonElement element) {
        return (element instanceof JsonNull) ? "" : element.getAsString();
    }
```

and call this method like this

```
thumbnail = checkIfNull(jsonResult.getString("thumbnail")
```

If its null, it will give you empty string if you are using **Gson**

and if you are using **JSONObject** then you can check with opt like this

```
thumbnail = jsonResult.optString("thumbnail"," ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to check key is available or not

```
 if(jsonResult.hasKey("thumbnail"){
 if ( jsonResult.getString("thumbnail")== null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Image Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.sikarlogo).into(imageView);
                } else {
                    imageUrl  = jsonResult.getString("thumbnail");
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);

                }

 }
```

Comment: if ( jsonResult.has("thumbnail")) {
                            imageUrl  = jsonResult.getString("thumbnail");
                            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Image Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.sikarlogo).into(imageView);
                        }

Answer (score 1):

They have a way to check JSON object has the key or not, for better handling this king of cases.

```
jsonResult.has("thumbnail")
```

this will return you true or false if true means JSON has key or false JSON object don't have a key

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you have to check whether the "thumbnail "  key exist or not

```
 if (jsonResult.has("thumbnail")) {
String status = jsonResult.getString("thumbnail"));
}
```

Comment: if you think the answer is useful to others and satisfy your question kindly accept as a answer

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in which you can handle it -

**Using the `has` method-**

```
    if(jsonResult.has("thumbnail"){
    ..your logic
    }
```

**Using the `isNull` method-**

```
    if(!jsonResult.isNull("thumbnail"){
    ..thumnail key is not present
    }
```

You can also use `optString` [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists, coercing it if
>   necessary, or fallback if no such mapping exists.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing `jsonResult.getString("thumbnail") == null` you can check if a response has thumbnail key or not by using `jsonResult.has("thumbnail")` and do further process as per your need.